# Google contacts v3 integration with ASP.NET VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-contacts-api

I completed a google contacts integration and it worked until some time ago.

I started getting this error

The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Google.GData.Client.OAuthBase.GetOAuth2AccessToken(OAuth2Parameters parameters, String requestBody)   at Google.GData.Client.OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(OAuth2Parameters parameters)
   at Success.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)

and

Execution of request failed: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full   at Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute()
   at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32 retryCounter)
   at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute()
   at Google.GData.Client.Service.Query(Uri queryUri, DateTime ifModifiedSince, String etag, Int64& contentLength)
   at Google.GData.Client.Service.Query(FeedQuery feedQuery)
   at Google.GData.Client.Feed`1.get_AtomFeed()
   at Google.GData.Client.Feed`1.d__0.MoveNext()
   at Success.PrintAllContacts(ContactsRequest cr)

Please what could be the problem.

Please find my codes below

```
 Dim o2 As New OAuth2Parameters
            o2.ClientId = ""
            o2.ClientSecret = ""
            o2.RedirectUri = "http://localhost:6498/Success"
            o2.Scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"
            'o2.Scope = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds"
            o2.ApprovalPrompt = "force"
            Dim iURL As String = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(o2)
            Session("MailServer") = "Google"

            Response.Redirect(iURL)

and on http://localhost:6498/Success

o2.AccessCode = Request.QueryString("Code") 'After the user has allowed contacts...bring to this page
                OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(o2)

                Dim reqSettings As New RequestSettings("", "tobi.omitiran@gmail.com")
                reqSettings.OAuth2Parameters = o2
                reqSettings.

                Dim contReq As New ContactsRequest(reqSettings)
                Dim Contacts As Feed(Of Google.Contacts.Contact) = contReq.GetContacts()

                Dim Name As String = Nothing
                Dim iEmail As String = ""
                Dim iPhone As String = Nothing

                For Each objContact As Google.Contacts.Contact In Contacts.Entries
                    Dim iName As Name = objContact.Name

                    For Each emailId As EMail In objContact.Emails
                        iEmail = iEmail & emailId.Address.ToString() & ";"
                    Next
                    For Each Phone As PhoneNumber In objContact.Phonenumbers
                        iPhone = iPhone & Phone.Home.ToString() & "," & Phone.Work.ToString() & ","
                    Next

                    BLL.WriteLog(iName.FullName)
                    BLL.WriteLog(iEmail)
                    BLL.WriteLog(iPhone)

                    DL.Insert_Lead(iName.FullName, iEmail, iPhone, Session("iLeadInvite"))
                Next
```

Comment: I think the ClientId as required to make a request.

Comment: Could you provide more detail like the line where it is failing, if the values in the object o2 are valid when requesting the access token and  when requesting the contacts.

Comment: The clientid is present, I just took out before making the question public.@thelotus

Comment: Getting the token is fine @Gerardo, the part the issues begin is when I try to retrieve the contacts. Dim Contacts As Feed(Of Google.Contacts.Contact) = contReq.GetContacts()

Comment: And at this point how variables like rqSettings look like? are you able to debug it?  can you reproduce it in the OAuth playground? https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: How does this work? I can see a difference in the permissions page. I get the "Have offline Access" permission instead of "Manage contacts" What could be the problem?